# Adding data from an array to a new column in a file using bash

Tags: bash, unix

So I have Name age and city data:

```
name=(Alex Barbara Connor Daniel Matt Peter Stan)
age=(22 23 55 32 21 8 89)
city=(London Manchester Rome Alberta Naples Detroit Amsterdam)
```

and I want to set up the following as 3 column data with the headings Name Age and city, I can easily get the first column  using

```
touch info.txt
echo "Name Age City" > info.txt
for n in ${name[@]}; do
    echo $n >> info.txt
done
```

but I can't figure how to get the rest of the data, and I can't seem to find anywhere on how to add data that's different as a new column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
name=(Alex Barbara Connor Daniel Matt Peter Stan)
age=(22 23 55 32 21 8 89)
city=(London Manchester Rome Alberta Naples Detroit Amsterdam)

touch info.txt
echo "Name Age City" > info.txt
for n in $(seq 0 6); do
    echo ${name[$n]} ${age[$n]} ${city[$n]} >> info.txt
done
```

Output in info.txt:

```
Name Age City
Alex 22 London
Barbara 23 Manchester
Connor 55 Rome
Daniel 32 Alberta
Matt 21 Naples
Peter 8 Detroit
Stan 89 Amsterdam
```

Comment: An alternative loop: `for ((n=0; n<${#name[@]}; n++))`

Comment: you can also use printf instead of echo to fix the width. check my answer below. Nice work

Comment: @Cyrus `for n in "${!name[@]}"` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you! I'm very new to bash and new I needed some way to get numbers 1->7 but couldn't find anything so huge thank you!

Comment: @user15192788 just take into account that the array index starts in 0, not in 1. So it should be $(seq 0 6) . I just edited my answer to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix a specific width for each column (here 20 is used)

```sh
name=(Alex Barbara Connor Daniel Matt Peter Stan)
age=(22 23 55 32 21 8 89)
city=(London Manchester Rome Alberta Naples Detroit Amsterdam)

for i in "${!name[@]}"; do
    printf "%-20s %-20s %-20s\n" "${name[i]}" "${age[i]}" "${city[i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
Alex                 22                   London              
Barbara              23                   Manchester          
Connor               55                   Rome                
Daniel               32                   Alberta             
Matt                 21                   Naples              
Peter                8                    Detroit             
Stan                 89                   Amsterdam
```

Answer (score 1):

JoseLinares solved your problem. For your information, here is a solution with the `paste` command whose purpose is exactly that: putting data from different sources in separate columns.

```
$ printf 'Name\tAge\tCity\n'
$ paste <(printf '%s\n' "${name[@]}") \
        <(printf '%3d\n' "${age[@]}") \
        <(printf '%s\n' "${city[@]}")

Name    Age City
Alex     22 London
Barbara  23 Manchester
Connor   55 Rome
Daniel   32 Alberta
Matt     21 Naples
Peter     8 Detroit
Stan     89 Amsterdam
```